# Criar html dinâmico através de javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema (para estudo) e me deparei com uma situação e pensei nas possibilidades diferentes de fazê-la. No meu site, ao clicar no botão "Criar caixa" deverá ser criada uma **div** com imagens, textos, outras divs que estão dentro de outras divs, resumindo, muito código html. Eu normalmente faço esse tipo de coisa utilizando o método createElement(), entretanto, com essa quantidade de html o código javascript ficaria muito complexo e confuso, daí eu tive uma ideia de jogar todo o html dentro de uma função javascript e retorna-lo, fazendo com que através do innerHTML eu pudesse adicionar quantos caixas eu quisesse apenas clicando no botão "Criar caixa". Aí vem a questão, essa é uma forma aceitável de criar html dinâmico? Isto é, seria ou boa ou má prática? Se é uma má prática, como um desenvolvedor experiente faria?

Exemplo:

```
//Essa função está em arquivo separado
function htmlCode() {
    return '<div> MUITO CÓDIGO HTML AQUI </div>';
}
...

<div id="container"></div>
<input type="button" id="addBox" /> 

...
<script> document.getElementById('addBox').onclick = function() { 
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += htmlCode();
} </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Pode usar a tag *template*:**

Referência:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp

```js
function showContent() {
  var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
  var clon = temp.content.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.appendChild(clon);
}
```

```html
<!--Exemplo-->
<template>
  <h2>Flores</h2>
<h3>Flor é a estrutura reprodutora característica das plantas angiospérmicas. Sua função é produzir sementes através da reprodução sexuada. Para as plantas, as sementes representam o embrião, que irá germinar quando entrar em contato com um substrato propício; as sementes são o principal meio através do qual as espécies de espermatófitas se perpetuam e se propagam.</h3>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_white_flower.jpg" width="214" height="204">
</template>


<h1>A tag template</h1>

<p>Clique no botão para obter o conteúdo de um modelo e exibi-lo na página da web.</p>

<button onclick="showContent()">Show content</button>

<template>
  <h2>Flower</h2>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_white_flower.jpg" width="214" height="204">
</template>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era realmente isso que eu precisava.